# Why am I getting this error: "error: { expected" in JCreator?

Tags: java

I am in an introductory networking class this semester and we are working with Server/Client chat rooms. This is my Server program so far, and I can't figure out why I'm getting the error in the title. It show the error on lines 17, 33, and 53, which are all lines where I've named new classes.
Any help with me appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new MyServer().start(); //Creates new Server for Clients to connect
    }


}

public class MyServer() extends Thread
{
    ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(11200);
    Socket S;
    ClientManager CM = new ClientManager();

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            S = SS.Accept; //Endless loop allowing clients to repeatedly connect
            CM.Add(); //Calls the Add method in ClientManager, which adds the Client to the Array
        }
    }
}

public class MyClient() extends Thread
{
    MyClient Client = new MyClient(Socket, CM);
    Scanner S;

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            S = new Scanner(System.in);
            CM.SendToAllClients(S); //Calls the method that will send each client the received message
        }
    }

    public void Send(String S)
    {
        PrintWriter.println(S);
    }       
}

public class ClientManager()
{
    MyClient[] X = new MyClient[15];
    int num = 0;

    public synchronized void Add(MyClient C)
    {
        X[num] = C;
        num++;
        C.start();
    }

    public synchronized void SendToAllClient(String S)
    {
        for(i = 0;i < num;i++);
        {
            X[i].Send(S);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `public class MyServer() extends Thread` should be `public class MyServer extends Thread`?

Comment: Also as a side note, ``MyClient`` and ``MyServer`` should probably ``implements Runnable`` and not ``extends Thread``

Comment: As a tip, you'll want to start methods and variable names with a lower case letter. I'm not just saying this because it's the "normal style"; it'll help with code readability later on down the road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `()` after your class names:

```
public class MyServer extends Thread {...}

public class MyClient extends Thread {...}

public class ClientManager {...}
```

Comment: This cleared the problems I was having earlier, but introduced several more I will have to look through. Thank you!